# How to give user credentials to create a contact in Contact Api V3(.Net)

Tags: .net, vb.net, api, google-api, google-contacts-api

I need to create an application for managing contacts.  Once I add a contact into my DB it will automatically update in Google contacts.

I try to create a google contact through my application using Contact API V3. I have referred to [this link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) to do this.

Here I don't know where to give the user credentials(Username & Password).

Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

There are two scenarios here:

1.If you want to add contacts to yourself, then enter the clientid and client secret in the code(which you get when application is registered in the Google developers console) itself. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2) for the documentation.

2.When you want to add contacts to the users of your application:

Requests to the Google Contacts API for non-public user data must be authorized by an authenticated user. Google authenticates with Oauth 2.0 where user is prompted to give the user id and password(for the first time) to authenticate the application to access user's data. Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) for the documentation.

Also, you try using oauth [playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) to see how oauth works.